# UI-Router state.go call back on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need a callback when state.go has been invoked successfully, and set my alert message.
Currently the message is pushed to the array, after state.go has been called.
State.go calls the controller, and the array containing the alert message is set to empty.

Result, no alert message will be shown.

Controller:

```
$scope.alerts = []; // empty array, initialized on startup
.....
// This could be any function
.success(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText){
     $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload : true});
     $scope.alerts.push({type : 'success', msg : status});
})
.error(function(error){
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload : true});`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`$state.go()` returns a promise.

So do something like:

```
$state.go('wherever', {whenever: 'whatever'}).then(function() {
  // Get in a spaceship and fly to Jupiter, or whatever your callback does.
});
```

Comment: Thank a lot

    $scope.stateGo = function(href) {
        $state.go(href).then(function() {
           //do something 
        });
    }

//html

    <a data-ng-click="stateGo('app.manager.list-question')" href="#">

Answer (score 8):

You may use state change listener.

```
 $rootScope
            .$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    //show alert()
                });
```

See [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).

Comment: Using rootscope sucks. I don't like this answer at all. There must be a better way.

Comment: @Fuser97381 why does using rootscope suck?

Comment: @RocoCTZ polluting global variable space is generally viewed as a bad idea. In this particular case, it's bad because you're putting code in the global context that only needs to run on one specific context. It pollutes the global context, which is bad. Read more broadly on the issue here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: @Fuser97381 Although what you're saying is correct in general, it doesn't mean globals are ALWAYS bad. I definitely think thre should be a better way of doing this without rootscope, but using it doesn't seem terrible to me: You're trying to do something *across contexts*.

Comment: @Fuser97381Did you figure out the solution in the end?

Comment: I dont think is a bad idea since the routing is something happening in a global way and rootScope is global, also $stateChangeSuccess is not special for any state specifically, is general.