# State.go in JavaScript - wait until it completes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have add an JS code like below-

```
    exports.openTab = function(location)
    {
      var $state = app.getInjector().get( '$state' );
      var opts = {};
      var toParams = {};
      toParams.id = "myPage";

      $state.go(location, toParams, opts);

exports.executeUsecase();        

    };
```

Here state.go works fine and opens location, but problem is it immediately executes below executeUsecase(), code inside it has dependency over location opened. Can I ensure if my location is opened fine and then only call execute method? I have heard of "stateChangeSuccess" but not sure how can it be used to open an specific url location?

Comment: Is it the same question as this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785168/ui-router-state-go-call-back-on-state-change

Comment: have a look on this .....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785168/ui-router-state-go-call-back-on-state-change

Comment: I did went through this thread earlier , .thn runs immediately after state.go(), in my usecase I want to wait until it succeeds. stateChangeSuccess seems to work for me but not sure how can I use it.

Comment: Check whether `$state.go()` has support for callback

Comment: `$state.go()` return a Promise, so `$state.go().then(() => { // do stuff })` [See doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

Comment: I have done exact similar thing, but before doing some stuff in then block, it has been ensured that location is loaded fully and succesfully. In current situation, stuff inside then executes immediately..

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of usage of "stateChangeSuccess".
This event will be triggered after each state transition.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) { 
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (fromState.name == "") { 
           //Do something
       }

    //Or

        if (toState.name == "") { 
           //Do something
       }
   });
});
```

Put necessary checks on "fromState.name" and "toState.name" according to your requirement.

Comment: I am not looking for doing something on every transition, I just need to execute my method once state.go() transition initiated by my code is completed.